# Does Apache detect tomcat redeployment process?

Tags: tomcat, webserver

I have an apache webserver, tomcatA and tomcatB with mod_jk setup.

I am wondering what would happen if tomcatA is redeploying and the client is trying to connect TomcatA.

Is there an way for apache to know the redeployment and transfer the client to TomcatB?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [FarmWarDeployer](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/cluster-deployer.html). Just add this to your cluster tag in your tomcat nodes and adjust the directories:

```
<Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
    deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
    watchEnabled="false"/>
```

Comment: I have done that. I am asking about whether httpclient or webbrowser would be redirected to tomcatB by apache when a tomcatA is redeploying.